# Identify USB port in UDev path in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I'm trying to identify USB keyboards by the physical port it's connected to, including which USB hub.

From experiments I've identified the following:

```
/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4.2/1-1.2.4.2:1.0/0003:0461:0010.0024/input/input49/event4
```

The first part, `/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/` appears to be constant given a system.
I guess it might be different on another system.

The last part, `/input/input49/event4` appears to be increasing every insertion.

Each part starting with `/1-1` appears to represent one hub in the USB chain, every later one starting with the full path of the previous one.

The last part in the `/1-1` chain contains `:` which identifies sub components inside that USB device.
However only the second number in `:1.0` appears to correlate with interface number, the first one is always `1` and I'm not sure how it could change or what that would mean.

My guess would be to identify the last part not containing `:` and use that as the physical USB path.

`0003` looks like it could be USB class: HID
`0461:0010` looks like VID:PID
`0024` Increases by every insertion

Are my assumption correct?
Is there a reliable way to identify location in the USB Port tree from either UDev path other means?

Comment: `libinput` knows which device is what type of, no need to do it in a custom way.

Comment: @0andriy search results for `libinput` returns Wayland references, looking through some of those results didn't contain anything relating to physical USB paths.

Comment: You need `libinput` to identify your keyboard or whatever. Then you may map it to the USB port. You may do other way around, subscribe to USB events (via `libusb`) and filter out your device by IDs and / or serial number, etc.

Comment: @andriy as the questions first sentence, I'm not trying to identify by id or serial number, only physical USB path. I'm 90% sure the rest of the question is correct in its findings and therefore looking for documentation to verify it and its reliability over time.